# stl - Is a string a vector?

Tags: c++, string, vector, stl

I have encountered a question in some quiz 
"*`Is a string a vector? If yes, in what way? If no, why not?`*"
Both of them have random access to the content.
But string has some methods which vector dosn`t.It also might have reference count .
So it is obvious that string is not exactly a vector (typedef string vector)
Are there known implementations  in which `class string : public vector <char>`?
If not - what is the reason for not implementing it so?

Comment: String has some methods which vector dosn`t? the reverse of that is true.

Comment: @MehdiTaxir - for exammple c_str() or data() or find_first_of() etc

Comment: Note: C++11 explicitly forbids reference counted strings

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas - why?

Comment: @Yakov - There were several big reasons for it (you can read the meeting notes at openstd.org).  One of the big ones was they wanted `std::string` to behave consistently across all implementations.  The copy-on-write implementations had some considerations you had to make that did not occur with those that did not try to reference count strings.

Comment: @Yakov: Besides the consistent behavior there are other issues in multithreaded environments due to the process of *unsharing* the buffer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From a purely philosophical point of view:  yes, a string is a *type* of vector.  It is a contiguous memory block that stores characters (a vector is a contiguous memory block that stores objects of arbitrary types).  So, from this perspective, a string is a special kind of vector.

In terms of design and implementation of `std::string` and `std::vector`, they share some of the same interface elements (e.g. contiguous memory blocks, `operator[]`), but `std::string` does **not** derive from `std::vector` (side note:  you should not publicly derive from standard containers as they are not designed to be based classes - e.g. they do not have virtual destructors), nor are they directly convertible to each other.  That is, the following will not compile:

```
std::string s = "abc";
std::vector<char> v = s; // ERROR!
```

However, since they both have iterator support, you can convert a string to a vector:

```
std::string s = "abc";
std::vector<char> v(s.begin(), s.end()); // note that the vector will NOT include the '\0' character
```

`std::string` will no longer have a reference count (as of C++11) as the copy-on-write functionality that many implementations used was forbidden by the C++11 standard.

From a memory perspective, an instance of `std::string` will look very *similar* to a `std::vector<char>` (e.g. they both will have a pointer to their memory location, a size, a capacity), but the functionality of the two classes is different.

Comment: "you should not publicly derive from standard containers as they do not have virtual destructors". Hmm, I think that is largely true, but glosses over it a bit. I would insert some text into the middle: "You should not publicly derive from standard containers as they are not designed to be used as base classes. One clue to this is that they do not have virtual destructors." It is not the only reason, and is not entirely a reason in itself.

Comment: Just a nit on the vocabulary, but a vector doesn't store types, it stores objects of an arbitrary type.  (More or less: the objects must be copyable, for example.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Fair enough.  The main point I was trying to get across there is that you can look at a string as a type of specialized vector, but you cannot look at a vector as a string.

Answer (score 11):

`std::string` has a non-trivial part of it's interface in common with `std::vector` (and other standard containers), but it is very definitely a different thing, with a different purpose.

It may also be implemented very differently, as it allows for things like the small string optimisation, or copy-on-write (not legal since 2011). (Although it is certainly possible for them to have very similar implementations).

They both support random access iterators, so can be used in similar ways with standard algorithms. I *think* `std::string` can not be classified as a sequence container.

It would not be possible to implement many of `std::string`'s member functions directly by inheriting from `std::vector`, because it hides the fact that it is also storing a `NUL`-terminator. So when `std::string::size` returns `3`, `std::vector::size` would return `4`, for instance. Same goes for `end`, and a few others.

Answer (score 3):

No, `std::string`(`std::basic_string<char>`), you can think of it a type of sequence container that contains `char` as it shares many functions with other containers, but it's not implemented using `std::vector`.

Answer (score 3):

The main reason that it can't (or at least certainly shouldn't be) implemented using public inheritance is that implicit conversion from `string` to `vector` shouldn't be allowed. For example, if I write code like:

```
int f(std::vector<char> const &s);

// ...

std::string s;
f(s);
```

Compilation should fail (absent some other overload of `f` that accepts a `string`).

If you really wanted to, you *could* (probably) do a legitimate implementation of `std::string` using *private* inheritance from `std::vector` though. It might not be as efficient as possible, but at least offhand, I can't think of a requirement it would obviously violate. The loss of efficiency would be from the fact that `std::vector` is required to be somewhat more general--it must support instantiation over types that can throw exceptions, whereas `std::string` is only designed to be instantiated over types that are exception free.

Comment: Another reason it cannot be implemented using public inheritance is the lack of a virtual destructor (for any of the std containers).

Comment: @ZacHowland Well the idea is I suppose that the inheritance would just be an implementation detail no user would know about, so they would never be storing a `std::vector<char>*` to a `std::string`, and certainly not `delete`ing it.