# Why is string not a (subclass of) vector?

Tags: c++

C strings are char arrays.

Vectors are the new arrays in C++.

Why aren't strings vectors (of chars) then?

Most of the methods of vectors and strings seem duplicated too. Is there a reason for making strings a different thing in C++?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19730488/stl-is-a-string-a-vector

Comment: vectors are not the new arrays in C++. arrays are the new arrays in C++ ;). More precisely: `std::array` is what comes closest to a c-style array

Comment: simple answer short: subclassing models a "is-a" relationship. A vector can contain any sort of elements. A string cannot contain any sort of elements. Ergo: strings are not vectors.

Comment: See the answer of BoBTFish here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19730488/stl-is-a-string-a-vector

Comment: ps: There even might be an implementation of strings that uses a vector under the hood. However, when using such a string you will not notice, because this is an implementation detail (and thus should not leak to the public interface).

Comment: The small string optimization is a good reason not to make a string a vector of chars (though it could still have a vector as a member for non-small strings, I guess). I disagree about the null terminator thing. C++ strings don't have to have a null terminator and if implementing `c_str()` is a concern, you can always make sure the vector has a capacity of at least `size()+1` and that `[size()]=='\0'` and then `c_str()` the same as `begin()`.

Comment: @tobi303: None of these are compelling reasons. However, the presence of a terminating nul character is. Several duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2436762/572743 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418145/why-isnt-stdstring-a-specialization-of-stdvector

Comment: @Damon a `vector<char>` subclass `string` could simply ensure it has a capacity of at least `size()+1` and that `[size()]=='\0'` and then `c_str()` is just `begin()`.

Comment: @PSkocik How would that work when you treat the `string` as its base `vector` and call `push_back`?

Comment: @MarkB Very easily: `const char* string::c_str() { reserve(size()+1); (*this)[size()]='\0'; return begin(); }`. No override for `push_back` required.

Comment: @PSkocik `c_str` is const though so the actual string object could be const too (can't cast away constness). You could still implement `string` with a mutable vector member though.

Comment: @PSkocik, calling `c_str()` must not invalidate existing iterators, pointers and references. If the `reserve` call needed to reallocate then it would invalidate, so your suggestion cannot be conforming.

Comment: Good point. It's still doable though. You'd just need make the '\0' at `*(end())` an invariant that you'd enforce in ctors and in every non-const operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty much just historical. Strings and vectors were developed in parallel with little thought going to how they could be considered one and the same, for `T==char`.

That's also why standard containers are nice and generic, whereas `std::basic_string` is a total monolith of member function after member function.

Edge case optimisation opportunities since made it difficult or impossible to transform `std::basic_string<T, Alloc>` into `std::vector<T, Alloc>` in any sort of standard way. Take the small string optimisation, for example. Although, now that GCC's copy-on-write mechanism is officially dead, we're a little closer.

The ability to legally dereference `std::string::end()` (and obtain `'\0'` for your trouble) is still problematic, though. A bunch of fairly stringent iterator invalidation rules for `.c_str()` basically prevent us from using `std::vector<char>` for this right from the start.

**tl;dr: this is what happens when you create a camel**

Comment: @JonathanWakely: I thought SSO was non-compliant (especially so from C++11 with those standard ambiguities & defects resolved) and that even GCC was migrating to a compliant `std::string` implementation now/soon? Fully admit I haven't bothered with much detailed research for this particular question as it's meant to give only a general idea. Still, I would of course remove factual inaccuracies...

Comment: This is news to me. COW is dead, and GCC 5.1 moved to SSO, is that what you're thinking of?

Comment: "Although, now that GCC's copy-on-write mechanism is officially dead, we're a little closer." Not really, while this particular obstacle has been removed, there is a new one: The committee took care to allow small string optimization for basic_string in C++11, but small vector optimization is/remains forbidden by virtue of mandating that pointers and references shall remain valid across a move or swap, and even mandating that elements must not be moved, copied or swapped (in the general container requirements, see §23.2.1/8 in N3376).

Comment: @ArneVogel: One step forwards, one step backwards, was the idea I was trying to put forth.

Comment: A camel? Why a camel?

Comment: @Barry: Because a camel is a horse designed by committee.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Never heard that before. Love it.

Answer (score 2):

The various answers in [Vector vs string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557009/vector-vs-string) show several differences in interfaces between `vector` and `string`, and since the typical pattern in the standard is to use static polymorphism rather than dynamic, they were created as two different classes.

Since strings do have different characteristics from vectors it doesn't seem that you would want to use public inheritance but I don't think there's anything in the standard that would prohibit protected or private inheritance, or composition to provide the underlying space management.

Additionally I suspect that `string` may have been developed earlier and orthogonally to `vector` which likely explains why there are member methods that more likely would have been made free algorithms if developed in parallel to `vector`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes because vector is a container which can contain T and std::string is a wrapper around char* and can't contain int or other datatypes. Wouldn't make any sense to have it any other way.

Comment: I guess the questions is why is std::string not a typedef for std::vector<char>.

Comment: Too vague. You could have `typedef vector<char> string;` which ostensibly makes perfect sense. In reality, modelling a string as a vector would cause all sorts of problems with short strings and null terminators.

Comment: @MagunRa nope, he is explicitly asking for subclassing